# ¿"Para que pueda (yo)" es una construcción extraña o incorrecta?

Tags: subjuntivo

https://pl.hinative.com/questions/24414683

Aquí dos personas me han escrito que decir "Para que pueda (yo)" es erróneo o extraño. ¿Cómo es eso? A me mí parece el uso del subjuntivo más estandar que haya.

¿Es incorrecto (o extraño) decir "Para que pueda (yo)"?

Answer (score 4):

**Para que pueda yo** es una construcción correcta. En el [CORDE](https://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) se pueden encontrar ejemplos de su uso, como los siguientes:

> "Cuéntame, pues, lo que haya pasado y el daño que hayas sufrido, **para que pueda yo** ponerle remedio!"  (Blasco Ibáñez, Vicente, traducción de Las mil y una noches)

> De todos modos, dígame usted qué especie de matrícula es la suya **para que pueda yo** contestar con toda seguridad.  (Menéndez Pelayo, Marcelino, Carta de 7 de agosto de 1887)

y ejemplos de uso de **para que pueda** (sin el **yo**):

> ... que el joven trabajador tenga sobre el oficio que desempeña el concepto lo más amplio y completo posible, **para que pueda** descubrir la significación de su tarea personal, ... (Brugarola, Martín, Sociología y Teología de la técnica, 1967)